# Magento 2: Not able to save data in database

Tags: magento2, database, customer, add

I am fetching customer Id from magento customer model and a data from custom page and trying to save it in databse.

```
<?php
namespace SimpleMagento\Milkman\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use SimpleMagento\Milkman\Model\PrepaidFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory;

class AfterPrepaid extends Action
{
    protected $prepaid;
    protected $result;
    protected $customer;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PrepaidFactory $prepaid,
        ResultFactory $result,
        SessionFactory $customer
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->result = $result;
        $this->prepaid = $prepaid;
        $this->customer = $customer;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $prepaidModel = $this->prepaid->create();
        $entity = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $modelcustomer = $this->customer->create();
        $id = $modelcustomer->getCustomer()->getId();
        //$data = $modelcustomer->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')->setOrder('entity_id','DESC');
        $prepaidModel->addData([
            "customer_id" => $id,
            "amount" => $entity['amount']
        ]);
        $model = $prepaidModel->save();
        print_r($model);
    }
}

?>
```

But I am getting an error.

```
{"0":"The resource isn't set.","1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Framework\\Model\\AbstractModel->save() called at [app\/code\/SimpleMagento\/Milkman\/Controller\/Account\/AfterPrepaid.php:39]\n#2 SimpleMagento\\Milkman\\Controller\\Account\\AfterPrepaid->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php:107]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#4 SimpleMagento\\Milkman\\Controller\\Account\\AfterPrepaid\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#5 SimpleMagento\\Milkman\\Controller\\Account\\AfterPrepaid\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#6 SimpleMagento\\Milkman\\Controller\\Account\\AfterPrepaid\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#), array(array('designLoader', 'customerNotifica...', 'catalog_app_acti...', 'tax-app-action-d...', 'weee-app-action-...', 'storeCheck', 'contextPlugin', 'customer-app-act...'))) called at [generated\/code\/SimpleMagento\/Milkman\/Controller\/Account\/AfterPrepaid\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#7 SimpleMagento\\Milkman\\Controller\\Account\\AfterPrepaid\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:55]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#9 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#10 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]\n#11 Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#00000000350c1720000000000ab7720e#, &Closure#00000000350c1723000000000ab7720e#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#12 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]\n#13 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#00000000350c1720000000000ab7720e#, &Closure#00000000350c1723000000000ab7720e#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#14 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#15 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#), NULL) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000350c1676000000000ab7720e#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:136]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:257]\n#18 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#00000000350c1692000000000ab7720e#) called at [index.php:39]\n<\/pre>","url":"\/magento\/milkman\/Account\/AfterPrepaid\/?amount=1500","script_name":"\/magento\/index.php"}
```

Install Schema :-

```
<?php
namespace SimpleMagento\Milkman\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $table_two = $setup->getTable('prepaid');

        $tableTwoSetup = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($table_two
        )->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [
                'identity' => true,
                'nullable' => false,
                'primary' => true
            ],
            'ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'customer_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [
                'nullable'=> false
            ],
            'Customer Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'amount',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [
                'nullable'=>false
            ],
            'Amount for postpaid'
        )->setComment("Prepaid_Table");

        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($tableTwoSetup);


        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: please try `$prepremode->setData)` instread of `$prepremode-addtData)`

Comment: checked..but not working @WaqarAli

Answer (score 0):

Check if your prepaidModel has a   constructor with two underlines (__construct)  .If exists check if this is valid method e.g passes all parameters correctly for its parent .  This methods  calls _construct - with one underline-  inside it that initiates correctly your resourceModel.
For a _construct (one underline) correct method, check below:
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html